# Function composition in R: extending example from closures

Tags: r, function

I am trying to create a minimalist example of function composition starting from [Wickham's example on closures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html)

This works:

```
power <- function(exponent, base_f) {
  base_f <-   function(x) {
    x ^ exponent
  }  
  base_f
  }

square <- power(exponent = 3)
square(x = 2)
```

But this does not:

```
base_f <-   function(x) {   
  x ^ exponent 
}  

power <- function(exponent, base_f) {     
  res1 <- base_f(x)     
  return(res1)   
}


square <- power(exponent = 3) 
square(x = 2)
```

Why?

I am looking for a solution that separates both functions.

Comment: The second attempt has a single object, an expression as its parameter. It's nto going to populate a named parameter list. The R interpreter is not set up to handle expressions with multiple named contributions.It's unclear tomy reading what you mean by "solution that separates both functions".. Both what functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems in the second example.

Firstly, `power` is referring to `x` which is not defined.  You want `res <- base_f`,
not `res <- base_f(x)`

Secondly, note that R uses lexical scoping.  That means that when a variable is referenced in a function and that variable is not also defined previously in that function then it looks to the function's lexical environment, i.e. it looks into the environment in which the function was *defined* -- not the environment from which the function was called.

In the second example, `base_f` will not look into `power` for `exponent` but will look into the global environment since that is the lexical environment where `base_f` was defined.  Make a copy of `base_f` and set its environment to the current environment within `power`.

Thirdly, when calling `power` near the end of the code the second argument is missing.

Making these changes it works.  We have marked the changed or new lines with ## .

```
base_f <-   function(x) {   
  x ^ exponent 
}  

power <- function(exponent, base_f) {   
  environment(base_f) <- environment()  ##
  res1 <- base_f ##
  return(res1)   
}

square <- power(exponent = 3, base_f) ##
square(x = 2)
## [1] 8
```

Comment: Terrific! Thanks for such a great answer. Is the practice of redefining the environment (`environment(base_f) <- environment() `) common or more of a workaround? I am thinking in terms of composite functions (building function within functions). Thanks agains!

Comment: it's a workaround.  I don't think that it would be comomnly found.

Comment: do you have recommendations/examples on how to do composite fns? I look around and had some trouble finding a good starting point

Comment: Try `Compose` in the functional package or `compose` in the purrr package.